# Impact of transistor gate connected directly to a supply net/ internal supply

Tags: analog, reliability

The risk of connecting gate of transistor in analog design is not very much in latest process technologies.
But what is the impact of connected gate to power net unintentionally? Will it damage the device?
What about dummies and always-on switches that need to be connected this way?
What reliability issues can occur due to this?
How to fix this issue if it arises?
Does LVT/HVT type devices have any difference in the impact it causes due to gate tied to supply?

Comment: What transistor? What power net? At what voltage? Schematic please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting device gates to a power rail increases the risk of ESD damage. Many newer technologies don't allow a gate to be directly connected to a power rail.

If you *need* a gate signal to be permanently tied to a rail, use a TIEHI or TIELO block. This is a few MOSFETs that generate a logic '1' or '0' without FET gates directly connected to the rail:
[image: TIEHI]